# How to add legend to scatter plot in R

Tags: r, legend

This might be a very basic question, But this is very new to me and I am unable to understand the syntax. I have plotted a simple graph using command.

```
plot(t$pe,t$chl_small,col=t$pop)
```

and the I got the graph in different colors, colored as per $pop I am unable to see the classification. Which color belongs to what group. So I got to know I need to add a legend to it. I tried using this

```
legend(50000,10000,labels ,col=c('red', 'blue', 'green','skyblue'),cex=0.8)
```

But it is showing me this error

```
Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

I cannot understand the error and don't even know what to Google so I am asking here.

Comment: How is `labels` defined?

Comment: The error is saying that R is trying to convert an object of type closure (i.e. a function) to character. This means that one argument that you have passed to `legend` is a function and not an object coerceable to character. The only argument that can be the culprit in your example is `labels`, that is, coincidentally, also the name of a function... so, replace labels with a vector containing the labels...